# How to make an instance move

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got the following code and the flash events are all loaded properly. `ball` is a movie clip and is assigned a class.

```
var speedx: Number=5;
var speedy: Number=3;
var myball = new ball();
addChild(myball);
addEventListener(Event:ENTER_FRAME,ballmove);
function ballmove(e:Event):void{
    myball.x+=speedx; 
    myball.y+=speedy;
}
```

But now the instance `myball` won't move, it is just stuck at position `0,0`. Kindly help me and advice how to get this myball to move along a staright line..

If I had dragged and dropped the instance from the library, then

```
myball.x+=speedx;
myball.y+=speedy;
```

worked perfectly, but doesn't work after `addChild` is given.

Comment: Do you have any other code in your project?

Comment: Hi @Joseph. Welcome to StackOverflow. If the answer works for you please mark it as correct (click on tick mark). This way others can know there is a working solution. If not working, then please give some feedback so someone else can try help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you incorrectly used `Event:ENTER_FRAME` when it should be : `Event.ENTER_FRAME`. I wonder if there is a "silent" error? When testing movies, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to run the debugger (gives better feedback on issues/errors).

`var myball = new ball();` does not mean anything. You declare instance by using this logic : 
 **var *Name* : *Type of Data* = *Value***, In your code here you've said only that **var *Name* = *Value***. Surprisingly it works but I wonder if getting comfortable with that could lead to issues on bigger future projects?

Instance name only affects objects already on Stage. If you're adding by code (from Library) make sure you create a new instance of object by using its **Linkage** name.

**Solution :** 
In the library, right-click the "ball" object and choose "**properties**", in there make sure **"name"** is `ball` and tick "**Export for ActionScript**" (you should see "**Class**" become`Class: ball`). OK that.

Now in your code, you can create new instance by : `var myball: ball = new ball();`...

Your code should look like

```
var speedx: Number=5;
var speedy: Number=3;
var myball: ball = new ball();

addChild(myball);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ballmove);

function ballmove(e:Event):void
{
    myball.x += speedx; 
    myball.y += speedy;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering: If the linkage wasn't working, there wouldn't be an instance sitting at position 0/0.

Comment: @null, Also he used `Event:ENTER_FRAME` instead of `Event.ENTER_FRAME` but didn't get the usual error... I could only suggest the best practice for a working solution (even if he's already covered some parts of it, like linkage etc)

Comment: That might actually be the real problem. Good find.